# Generating multiple input fields in one<td> dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to alter id and name of some input fields dynamically in a single td. I haven't given any class name for the td. But I think that is not the problem. Here only the last field name is created 3 times. Sample code is given below.

```
$(this).find('td:eq(3) > input').attr({
                    'id' : 'templateForm.fieldsArray['+fieldIndex+'].subArray['+subIndex+'].Templatedescription',
                    'name' : 'templateFormForm.fieldsArray['+fieldIndex+'].subArray['+subIndex+'].Templatedescription',
                    });

                    $(this).find('td:eq(3) > input').attr({
                    'id' : 'templateFormForm.fieldsArray['+fieldIndex+'].subArray['+subIndex+'].TemplateId',
                    'name' : 'templateFormForm.fieldsArray['+fieldIndex+'].subArray['+subIndex+'].TemplateId',
                    });
                    $(this).find('td:eq(3) > input').attr({
                    'id' : 'newMilestonetemplateForm.fieldsArray['+fieldIndex+'].subArray['+subIndex+'].TemplateName',
                    'name' : 'newMilestonetemplateForm.fieldsArray['+fieldIndex+'].subArray['+subIndex+'].TemplateName',
                    });
```

Comment: `td:eq(3) > input` selects all `input` elements that is a child of that `td`. So when you call `attr` three times, it applies the attributes to all of the input elements three times.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I solved the problem as shown below. Not sure any other method is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem this way.

```
$(this).find('td:eq(3) > input:eq(0)').attr({
                    'id' : 'templateForm.fieldsArray['+fieldIndex+'].subArray['+subIndex+'].Templatedescription',
                    'name' : 'templateFormForm.fieldsArray['+fieldIndex+'].subArray['+subIndex+'].Templatedescription',
                    });

                    $(this).find('td:eq(3) > input:eq(1)').attr({
                    'id' : 'templateFormForm.fieldsArray['+fieldIndex+'].subArray['+subIndex+'].TemplateId',
                    'name' : 'templateFormForm.fieldsArray['+fieldIndex+'].subArray['+subIndex+'].TemplateId',
                    });
                    $(this).find('td:eq(3) > input:eq(2)').attr({
                    'id' : 'newMilestonetemplateForm.fieldsArray['+fieldIndex+'].subArray['+subIndex+'].TemplateName',
                    'name' : 'newMilestonetemplateForm.fieldsArray['+fieldIndex+'].subArray['+subIndex+'].TemplateName',
                    });
```